# HTML5 Web Worker does not work on Mobile Safari iPad 4.2

Tags: html, mobile, safari, worker

I cannot make an instance of Worker on Mobile Safari on an iPad with OS 4.2x

This is a very common and well-known HTML5 Web Worker demo:  http://html5demos.com/worker

When I try to run I get the error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Worker

This demo works fine on desktop Safari.  My understanding was that with OS 4.2x that HTML5 Web Workers would be supported on mobile safari.  Does anyone know different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment WebWorkers are against Apple's policy on JavaScript runtimes. Even if it were supported it would be thrown out after 10 seconds as the maximum, non-blocking runtime.

Answer (score 2):

According to caniuse.com, it's [not yet supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=worker)